# What does MIBCC.EXE exactly do?

Tags: snmp

What does MIBCC.EXE do exactly ?

Please tell me what does it do ?

In some document I read that it means "The SNMP MIB Compiler"

I cant understand its mean .

Can you say a example of its work ?

Answer (score 2):

Compiling a New or Updated MIB File by Using Mibcc.exe:
As explained earlier, the SNMP-related branches of the MIB tree are located in the internet branch of the tree. The internet branch contains public branches that are defined by the IETF and private branches that are defined by large organizations. When an organization creates its own subset of MIB branches and objects, or updates an existing MIB file, the new or updated MIB file must be created in compliance with SMI-prescribed data types.

If your organization adds or updates a new MIB file, use the Mibcc.exe tool to compile the MIB file so that the SNMP Management API (Mgmtapi.dll) can use the MIB objects in the new or updated MIB file. After you compile the MIB file, you can reference objects by their text object identifiers instead of their numeric object identifiers. The ASN.1 language is used to define the formats of the protocol data units (PDUs) that are exchanged by SNMP entities and to define the objects that are managed through SNMP. Mibcc.exe converts the ASN.1 MIB description into the binary Mib.bin file, which the Management API then uses to map text-based object names to numeric object identifiers.

You can find Mibcc.exe in the C:\Program Files\Resource Kit folder when you install the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit companion CD. The Mib.bin file is located in systemroot on Windows Server 2003.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783142(WS.10).aspx

Comment: The Windows 2003 Resource Kit was not the first time Microsoft had distributed this program; for example, it's file `sdk/bin/winnt/mibcc.exe` in the October 1997 Platform SDK as distributed with Borland C++ 5.0.